# Encode in Python and decrypt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, encryption

I've searched for this, there are lots of hits, but I can't find one that is neither complete (pulls all the bits together) nor says its a bad idea, use HTTP. I've tried lots of things based on the hits I've found, but I can't get it to work.

The target problem is to AES encrypt textual data at one place, send it to a web API where it is stored in a database, then retrieve from the database via another API and decode it in the browser. This is not for security in transmission, it is so that, if the originator and the receiver know the key and IV, then it can be stored without the server knowing what the real content is.

The originator code is python, and the web API is python, so to make life easier initially, I'm storing the content unencrypted in the database. I've done AES encrypt/decrypt in python before, so that's not an issue. What I'm trying to do is encrypt in python as the content comes out of the database, transmit it, then decrypt in javascript. I've been using the python 'from Crypto.Cipher import AES' code, and javascript CryptoJS implementation from code.google.com

I'm happy at this stage to write the key and the IV into the code, distribution isn't really a problem as the originator and the client browser are effectively the same system.

I've not added any code because I think it would be more trouble than its worth at this stage.

Thanks in advance!

OK, some code. On the server python(3) side:

```
text = 'This is a message'
key = 'This is a key123'
iv = 'This is an IV456'
text += (16 - len(text) % 16) * ' '  # Pad to 16 chars, spaces are OK here
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
enc = base64.b64encode(aes.encrypt(text)).decode()
print(enc)
```

enc is passed along with other data, JSON encoded, as the response to an AJAX request. On the client javascript side:

```
enc = /* from JSON */ ;
console.log(enc) ;
key = 'This is a key123';
iv  = 'This is an IV456';
text = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(Base64.decode(enc), key,
           { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC })) ;
console.log(text)
```

The python print(enc) and the javascript console.log(env) are the same, so I know the b64'd encoded data is coming over OK. The console.log(text) (in Chrome) shows as

```
l.WordArray.t.extend.init { ... }'
```

and not 'This is a message'. So why not!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  Could you please clarify what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Use code to clarify your problem.

Comment: I'm assuming your looking to store encrypted content on a 3rd party DB but can't because you can't submit a BLOB object to it (containing your AES encrypted data)? If this assumption is correct, perhaps use python to encrypt the data, then encode it using base64. Then on the client end retrieving the data, use JS to base64 decode, then decrypt with CryptoJS? I presume the client should possess the credentials in some fashion?

Comment: @0xhughes: No, I can submit an encrypted blob. My immediate problem is to establish that I can encrypt in python on the server and decrypt in JS in the browser. Once I'm happy about that, I can push the encryption back to the client that generates the content in the first place (so the server never knows the key or the IV).

Comment: i don't think CryptoJS returns a printable string. Seems to be a WordArray that you would have to iterate over and convert to characters.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved, but another mystery**

I used the code from this gist:

https://gist.github.com/andres-erbsen/1307675

But: this uses code from http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/files/... which is not what you get from the download at https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/downloads/list. The gist code uses Crypto.xxxx names; the download code uses CryptoJS.xxxx names. The gist is 2 years old, has CryptoJS replaced Crypto maybe?